# Truffle test in solidity with sending value

Tags: solidity, truffle

duplicating my [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108184/truffle-test-in-solidity-with-sending-value) from SA:

I have a simple contract with public function, that can receive value and do something based on that value:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.8.0 < 0.9.0;

contract ContractA {


    uint public boughtItems = 0;
    uint price = 10;
    address []  buyers; 

    function buySomething() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= price, "Sent value is lower"); 
        boughtItems++;
        buyers.push(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

and in test folder of my Truffle project I have test contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/TicketsRoutes.sol";

contract TestTicketsRoutes {

    ContractA instance;
    

    address account1 = 0xD8Ce37FA3A1A61623705dac5dCb708Bb5eb9a125;

    function beforeAll() public {
        instance = new ContractA();
    }

    function testBuying() public {
        //Here I need to invoke buySomething with specific value from specific address
        instance.buySomething();

        Assert.equal(instance.boughtItems, 1, "Routes amount is not equal");
    }
}
```

How do I invoke function of ContractA in my TestContractA with passing value and sender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the low-level `call()` Solidity function to pass a value.

```
(bool success, bytes memory returnedData) = address(instance).call{value: 1 ether}(
    abi.encode(instance.buySomething.selector)
);
```

But, in order to execute the `buySomething()` function from a different sender, you need to send it from a different address than the `TestTicketsRoutes` deployed address.

So you'll need to change your approach and perform the test from an off-chain script (instead of the on-chain test contract) that allows you to sign the transaction from a different sender. Since you tagged the question `truffle`, here's an example of executing a contract function using the Truffle JS suite ([docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#making-a-transaction-via-a-contract-function)).

```
const instance = await MyContract.at(contractAddress);
const tx = await instance.buySomething({
    from: senderAddress,
    value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")
});
```